# Make sure refetchQueries only affect currently mounted components

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

In a React web app, using Apollo Client and typescript codegen hooks to do queries and mutations: My question is if there is a good way to make sure that Apollo does not automatically go and refetch queries that are connected to unmounted components?

Explanation:
I have an `Events` component that uses a `ListEvents` query hook to fetch events to show. It's being rendered various places within this Single Page Application, with different variables to show different types of events.

On some of the pages where I have an Events component, mutations are being made that could have the side effect of generating one or more events. These events are not exposed as a response to the mutation, so in order to make the Events component get up to date, I've had to add the ListEvents query to various mutations using `refetchQueries`.

This does technically work, but I've noticed a problematic side effect, and it seems like Apollo refetches multiple ListEvent queries that were tied to component instances that are now unmounted. All ListEvents queries that have been run during the current session is instantly triggered for refetch. This does not make sense, because I only want to refetch Events for components that are actually mounted. The cache-policy of "cache-and-network" should make sure that components should fetch up-to-date data whenever they get remounted again.

So the question is: Is this expected behaviour, that Apollo refetches all instances of the EventList query for the entire session even if just one of them are connected to a component that is currently mounted?

If so; What is a good way to fix this so it only goes to the server for the events that are being displayed to the user at the time of the mutation?

I suppose I could make unique GraphQL queries for each of the places I now use the same EventList query, but that seems like it would add quite a bit of added complexity and reduce the reusability potential of the Event queries (that are exactly the same, just with different filter variables).

For reference, here is a hook that is being used to query events:

```
  const { data } = useListEventsQuery({
    variables: {
      filter: { eventTypes: [...] },
      sort: [{ field: EventSortableField.CreatedAt, asc: false }],
      limit: 10,
      from: addDays(now, -1).toISOString(),
    },
  });
```

And here is a mutation that causes refetching

```
  const [updateReservation] = useUpdateAssetReservationsMutation({
    refetchQueries: [GqlOps.Query.ListEvents]
  });
```